# heic2any Argument of type 'Blob | Blob[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob'

Tags: typescript

I'm doing:

```
        const heicReader = new FileReader();

        heicReader.onload = async () => {
          const heicImageString = heicReader.result;

          const { download_url } = await uploadPhotoToGcs({
            base64: heicImageString,
            type: 'image/png',
          });
          this.onSubmitImageMessage(download_url);
        };

        const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imageData);
        const blobRes = await fetch(blobUrl);
        const imgBlob = await blobRes.blob();
        const convertedFile = await heic2any({ blob: imgBlob });

        heicReader.readAsDataURL(convertedFile);
        return;
```

And the `heicReader.readAsDataURL(convertedFile);` complains about:

```
const convertedFile: Blob | Blob[]
Argument of type 'Blob | Blob[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob'.
  Type 'Blob[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Blob': size, type, arrayBuffer, stream, text
```

What am I missing?

Comment: heic2any returns Blob | Blob[] while readAsDataURL method only takes Blob type arguments. An assertion can be helpful but is not the correct solution.

`heicReader.readAsDataURL(convertedFile as Blob);`

Comment: It can result in multiple blobs. What do you want to do when it returns an array of blobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it can return an array of blobs, you need to check if it is not an array before using it:

```
const convertedFile = await heic2any({ blob: imgBlob });

if (!Array.isArray(convertedFile)) heicReader.readAsDataURL(convertedFile);
else { /* convertedFile is an array of blobs */ }
```

but you should also consider the case if it is an array of blobs. Would you then try to read only the first one?

```
if (!Array.isArray(convertedFile)) heicReader.readAsDataURL(convertedFile);
else heicReader.readAsDataURL(convertedFile[0]));
```